# XSLT to Unordered List

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to take a xml document and transform to a standard html list with nesting:

**Sample**

```
<orgtree>
  <Node nodeID="1363" nodeDescription="Some User" nodeNote="Some Note" X="5260" Y="20">
    <Node nodeID="1373" nodeDescription="Some Child User" nodeNote="More">
      <Node nodeID="1374" nodeDescription="Another Child" nodeNote="More"/>
      <Node nodeID="1375" nodeDescription="Another Child" nodeNote="More"/>
      <Node nodeID="1376" nodeDescription="Another Child" nodeNote="More"/>
      <Node nodeID="1377" nodeDescription="Another Child" nodeNote="More"/>
    </Node>
    <Node nodeID="1474" nodeDescription="Another Child" nodeNote="More"/>
    <Node nodeID="1475" nodeDescription="Another Child" nodeNote="More"/>
  </Node>
</ogtree>
```

**I'd Like it to appear as:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Some User<br/>SomeNote
    <ul>
      <li>Some Child User<br/>More
        <ul>
          <li>Another Child<br/>More</li>
          <li>Another Child<br/>More</li>
          <li>Another Child<br/>More</li>
          <li>Another Child<br/>More</li>
        </ul>
      <li>Another Child<br/>More</li>
      <li>Another Child<br/>More</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: The Tree Can go on nesting forever, and each node can have multiple children.  I'd like to display the ul li the same way and I am as of yet unable to do this...Can someone give me a better way to transform? Each Node also have a graphical position for page viewing an image based on the node id.  (Though, I could care about this portion).

Comment: there is a small typo in your xml, the closing node `ogtree` does not match its start node `<orgtree>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic setup for a XSLT you would need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="orgtree">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>    
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeDescription"/>
    </li>
    <xsl:if test="Node">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It has a template that matches any `Node` element and applies this template for any of its children incase it has any `test="Node"`. This technique is known as [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

When learning XSLT I can recommend the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256069.aspx) for basic and advanced topics and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) for basics.

Comment: w3schools is not recommended. In fact check out w3fools for reasons why. Try http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/. Though I personally started here http://www.zvon.org/comp/m/xslt.html

Comment: true w3schools is not my goto solution...but, the xslt you provided is enough for me to do what I need.  I was just lost (maybe as of the late hour) to how to pull the attributes and nesting.

Comment: You had it right, excep to move the </li> to after the </xsl:if>  Thank you.